# Symfony 4 route not found

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm using routes by annotations and everything is fine except with this one specific route that I simply can't see the issue.

> NotFoundHttpException No route found for "PUT
>   /responder/questionario/1/questao/6/pessoa/2/resposta/11"

The route is mapped as following:

```
//Class route
/**
 * @Route("/responder")
 */
//Method route
/**
 * @Route("/questionario/{id}/questao/{qId}/pessoa/{pId}/resposta/{$rId}", name="api_responder_questionario_questao_resposta", methods="PUT")
 */
```

As you can see, is a PUT request and is the only that exists on the whole system so far.

The route debug returns that route (the last one in the list):

```
 --------------------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  Name                                          Method   Scheme   Host   Path                                                                     
 --------------------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ ------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  api_cargo_new                                 POST     ANY      ANY    /cargo/novo                                                              
  api_cargo_edit                                POST     ANY      ANY    /cargo/{id}/editar                                                       
  api_cargo_index                               GET      ANY      ANY    /cargo/                                                                  
  api_cargo_get                                 GET      ANY      ANY    /cargo/{id}                                                              
  api_empresa_new                               POST     ANY      ANY    /empresa/novo                                                            
  api_empresa_edit                              POST     ANY      ANY    /empresa/{id}/editar                                                     
  api_empresa_index                             GET      ANY      ANY    /empresa/                                                                
  api_empresa_get                               GET      ANY      ANY    /empresa/{id}                                                            
  api_frequencia_new                            POST     ANY      ANY    /frequencia/novo                                                         
  api_frequencia_edit                           POST     ANY      ANY    /frequencia/{id}/editar                                                  
  api_frequencia_index                          GET      ANY      ANY    /frequencia/                                                             
  api_frequencia_get                            GET      ANY      ANY    /frequencia/{id}                                                         
  api_perfilAcesso_new                          POST     ANY      ANY    /perfilAcesso/novo                                                       
  api_perfilAcesso_edit                         POST     ANY      ANY    /perfilAcesso/{id}/editar                                                
  api_perfilAcesso_index                        GET      ANY      ANY    /perfilAcesso/                                                           
  api_perfilAcesso_get                          GET      ANY      ANY    /perfilAcesso/{id}                                                       
  api_pessoa_new                                POST     ANY      ANY    /pessoa/novo                                                             
  api_pessoa_edit                               POST     ANY      ANY    /pessoa/{id}/editar                                                      
  api_pessoa_index                              GET      ANY      ANY    /pessoa/                                                                 
  api_pessoa_get                                GET      ANY      ANY    /pessoa/{id}                                                             
  api_questaoTipo_new                           POST     ANY      ANY    /questao/tipo/novo                                                       
  api_questaoTipo_edit                          POST     ANY      ANY    /questao/tipo/{id}/editar                                                
  api_questaoTipo_index                         GET      ANY      ANY    /questao/tipo/                                                           
  api_questaoTipo_get                           GET      ANY      ANY    /questao/tipo/{id}                                                       
  api_questionario_new                          POST     ANY      ANY    /questionario/novo                                                       
  api_questionario_edit                         POST     ANY      ANY    /questionario/{id}/editar                                                
  api_questionario_index                        GET      ANY      ANY    /questionario/                                                           
  api_questionario_get                          GET      ANY      ANY    /questionario/{id}                                                       
  api_questionario_questao_new                  POST     ANY      ANY    /questionario/{id}/questao/novo                                          
  api_questionario_questao_edit                 POST     ANY      ANY    /questionario/{id}/questao/{qId}                                         
  api_recompensa_new                            POST     ANY      ANY    /recompensa/novo                                                         
  api_recompensa_edit                           POST     ANY      ANY    /recompensa/{id}/editar                                                  
  api_recompensa_index                          GET      ANY      ANY    /recompensa/                                                             
  api_recompensa_get                            GET      ANY      ANY    /recompensa/{id}                                                         
  api_responder_index                           GET      ANY      ANY    /responder/                                                              
  api_responder_questionario_questao_resposta   PUT      ANY      ANY    /responder/questionario/{id}/questao/{qId}/pessoa/{pId}/resposta/{$rId}
```

The actions I already did was clearing cache, changing the priority of this request on the controller and later I created a controller for this case always clearing cache. This request was originally a GET but I changed to a PUT in a effort to make it more exclusively and easy to debug.

Comment: last route is `/responder/questionario/{id}/questao/{qId}/pessoa/{pId}/resposta/{$rId}` are you sure about the `$` for the last parameter ?

Comment: Thanks @Cid, you're right about the typo, i wrongly entered the entire variable name.
About the route, it was declared in the class, I added it to the question.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `methods={"PUT"}`?

Comment: @Pipe not necessarily.

Comment: Did you remove the $ as @Cid says? (Please update your code)

Comment: @Pipe, yes, I did. It worked as I said in response to Cid's comment, thanks!

Comment: @Cid feel free to post the answer.

Comment: @FelipeChagas no need, this isn't really a question since it's a typo rather than a real problem

Comment: @Cid Got it! I'll update the question and close it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cid answered in the comments: there was a typo on my code:

With error:

```
/**
 * @Route("/questionario/{id}/questao/{qId}/pessoa/{pId}/resposta/{$rId}", name="api_responder_questionario_questao_resposta", methods="PUT")
 */
```

Correct:

```
/**
 * @Route("/questionario/{id}/questao/{qId}/pessoa/{pId}/resposta/{rId}", name="api_responder_questionario_questao_resposta", methods="PUT")
 */
```

Comment: When you have an 'old' project, everything is already setup correctly (many working routes), and everything seems to be in place, it had to be something like this. Thanks for the hint.